# Demagnetization of permanent magnets due to external magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring something out.  I am aware that permanent magnets can be demagnetized due to strong enough external magnetic fields.  My question though, is whether this kind of demagnetization is linearly proportional to the strength of the external field or if there is a minimum external magnetic field strength required to affect the permanent magnet at all?

Is there a cutoff for this kind of demagnetization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with trying to demagnetize a ferromagnetic material with an external field is that when you remove the external field, the atomic dipoles tend to go back into alignment with the microscopic crystal axes. This leaves a “remnant” field (you still have a permanent magnet).  A “demagnetizer” (generally an AC electromagnet) is strong enough to align nearly all of the dipoles, but it alternates in direction, taking them repeatedly around the hysteresis loop.  As the demagnetizer moves away from the sample (or visa-versa), the loops get smaller and smaller, eventually leaving the sample with no remnant field.

Comment: Does this realignment release energy?

Comment: I believe so, in the form of heat.

Comment: I appreciate the answer R. W. Bird, but I'm not sure I understand.  What if I want to avoid demagnetization.  Does this happen in the presence of any external field or just one that's strong enough?

Comment: With a strong magnet I have been able to reverse the polarization of a compass needle, but while playing with magnets of comparable strength, I have not noticed that they effected each other.  Then again, the bar magnets used in my physics lab classes had to be re-magnetized periodically (due to a loss of strength).